# I want to use an interactive function to do something like vim's `gd n` in Emacs, search the current word in buffer

Tags: search

I want to use an interactive function to do the vim-like `gd n` in Emacs, search the current word in buffer

`gd` in vim will select current word(highlighting same words), and n will cycle selecting the current word in current file.
I used to use an interactive function(by google and copy), binding to 'M-n' to do this,
(or maybe it is a function in some package)
but a few days before my `.emacs.d` directory has lost by fault.
The last few days I've been searching for this function again and again and
did not get it.
Can any one help me with this?
By using this function, I can hit `M-n` just one time, the word
under/just-before/just-after point will be selected and point will
go to the next occurance of the same word under/just-before/just-after point.
thanks a lot!

---

Thank you all for your answers!

The key thing is here:
I should use the same kbd, say it is `M-n` to select the current word and to cycling all candidates.
so if I put point on a word, I just need to hit `M-n` multiple times to cycling all the same word in buffer.

Thanks!

Comment: Clarification: are you asking about the function, or how to bind the function to a key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: `C-s C-w`

Details: in `isearch`, `C-w` is bound to `isearch-yank-word-or-char` which usually puts the current word in the search query. If the point is on a punctuation mark, this char will be searched.

Another option is to use the package [smart-scan](https://github.com/mickeynp/smart-scan) (maybe it is what you had in your old `.emacs`) which searches for the current *symbol* forward (bound to `M-n` by default) and backwards (`M-p` by default).

Comment: smart-scan is exactly the one I used before! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll ask the author of smart-scan how to cycle in buffer and how cycle symbol and word, subword

Comment: `M-n` should cycle through the buffer. And as far as I can tell, symbol means word, unless subword-mode is activated, and then it means subword (isearch behaves the same way).

Comment: does M-n go to the beginning of the buffer when it hits the end ? For me it will stop on the last match

Answer (score 4):

You can use `M-s .` bound to `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` by default, and then `C-s` to search forward for that symbol ('word') or `C-r` to search backwards.

---

From `C-h f isearch-forward-symbol-at-point`:

> Do incremental search forward for a symbol found near point.
>   Like ordinary incremental search except that the symbol found at point
>   is added to the search string initially as a regexp surrounded
>   by symbol boundary constructs `\_<` and `\_>`.